# Implementing a ViewModel for entire the application

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, viewmodel

I want to build a viewModel for entire the application to send and receive data between multiple fragments and activities. so, how can I do that

Comment: It's not possible use a database or preferences or a singleton object

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: generally we use a viewmodel for using room database, so I need the same thing but without a database; to send simple data without losing it by any of configuration changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do not implement ViewModel scoped to the application

From Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel):

> The viewmodel of MVVM is a value converter, meaning the viewmodel is responsible for exposing (converting) the data objects from the model in such a way that objects are easily managed and presented. In this respect, the viewmodel is more model than view, and handles most if not all of the view's display logic. The viewmodel may implement a mediator pattern, organizing access to the back-end logic around the set of use cases supported by the view.

From `ViewModel` class [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel):

> ViewModel is a class that is responsible for preparing and managing the data for an Activity or a Fragment. It also handles the communication of the Activity / Fragment with the rest of the application (e.g. calling the business logic classes).
>
> A ViewModel is always created in association with a scope (a fragment or an activity) and will be retained as long as the scope is alive.
>
> ViewModel's only responsibility is to manage the data for the UI.

It's clearly defined that **ViewModel is a binder between View and Model and nothing more**. Currently only `Activity`, `Fragment` and their subclasses implement `ViewModelStoreOwner` interface allowing `ViewModel` be scoped to them.

Also `Application` scoped `ViewModel` violate the important [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principle - [Interface segregation (ISP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). It states following:

> ISP splits interfaces that are very large into smaller and more specific ones so that clients will only have to know about the methods that are of interest to them. Such shrunken interfaces are also called role interfaces. ISP is intended to keep a system decoupled and thus easier to refactor, change, and redeploy.

### How to send and receive data between activities and fragments?

Some ways to communicate easier than application `ViewModel`:

- Between activities via [Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)
- Between fragments via [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle), via [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) with [Safe Args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args) and via [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#viewmodel)
- Between activity and fragment via [Fragment.setArguments()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#setArguments(android.os.Bundle))